# Why is the image buffer of my ImageReader callback so big?

Tags: android, android-image, android-camera2

Within my `ImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener()` I have the following callback code:

```
previewImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener({ reader ->
    val image = reader.acquireLatestImage()
    var buffer = img.planes[0].buffer
    buffer.rewind()
    var size = buffer.remaining()
    var bytes = ByteArray(size)
    buffer.get(bytes)
    // do stuff with the received ByteArray
}
```

Here is the weird thing: For testing purposes I created the surface of the image reader with extremely small dimensions:

```
previewImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(4, 3, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1)
```

However, buffer.remaining() returns a number `>70.000`. Why is the buffer so big, even though the dimensions of the return image are 4x3 pixels?